# Integral $\int \frac {\text{d}x}{\sin^2 x + 2 \cos^2 x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Please can anybody help me to solve this integral:
$$\int \frac {\text{d}x}{\sin^2 x + 2 \cos^2 x}$$
Thank you very much.

Comment: you should $\tan \left( \dfrac {\theta } {2}\right) $  ??

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in this and future posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please [provide some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Comment: @fsuluova: Given that both $\sin$ and $\cos$ carry *even* powers, the substitution $x = \tan t$ is easier in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\frac{1}{\sin^2x+2\cos^2x}=\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan^2x+2}$. Then let $u=\tan x$

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^2x+2\cos^2x}dx=\int\frac{1}{u^2+2}du$$

We now let $u=\sqrt2\tan\theta$, which gives us

$$\int\frac{1}{u^2+2}du=\int\frac{\sqrt2\sec^2\theta}{2\sec^2\theta}d\theta=\frac{\theta}{\sqrt2}+c$$

Working backwards, we find this to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan(\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt2})+c$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:  $\sin^2x + 2\cos^2x = 1+\cos^2x = 1+\dfrac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}=\dfrac{3+\cos(2x)}{2}$, and followed by letting $u = 2x$ then it reduces to $I = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{du}{3+\cos u}$. From this you have a standard substitution $u = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$ as proposed.

Comment: you should take $\theta=tan \frac {u}{2}$